# Ethernet led flashes randomly

Tags: networking

Since a couple days, the white LED of the ethernet port of my HP 250 G7 flashes randomly, without any cable inserted. It is not docked and there is nothing in any of the ports. This happens on battery and on AC. This does not happen under Windows. I have a fully updated Ubuntu 22.04. I cannot find a correlation between the flashes and any other activity. `dmesg` shows no message when it happens, there is nothing stuck in the port. I cannot find anything related on Google. Can anyone help me diagnose this, please?

Comment: Sounds like a network sending out a DHCP message, requesting an IP address. Disable "Auto" connection in Network settings. To investigate, instsll `wireshark`, see https://www.wireshark.org

Comment: There is no cable plugged in: it shouldn't send anything... Anyway I will try with Wireshark, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how, but this seems to have stopped. The only thing I've done is uninstall and reinstall the wireless card driver [rtl8821ce](https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce). I didn't update the driver, so I don't know how it could be related and if this is what solved the problem.